# Can the iPhone only use an SQLite database?

Tags: iphone, database, cocoa-touch

Can the iPhone use other databases besides SQLite, like MySQL?

Comment: Could You elaborate? Why do You need a bigger database?

Comment: you may need to change some SQL statement for SQLite if you're directly porting from existing application with MySQL. Otherwise they work pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 5):

The iPhone can only use SQLite as a database, directly on the device. This means there is no MySQL server inside the iPhone. But you can, and are free to have (your own) MySQL Back-end server, to which iPhone applications connect to. But Apple doesn't provide the server, so you have to pay the maintenance costs

Answer (score 2):

Not true any more!

The Raima RDM Embedded database SDK will also work on the iPhone. It's cool because it supports the network and relational models, and you can do things like having direct pointers to records for faster access.

They have an official port coming, but their version for Mac works in the iPhone Simulator.

[raima.com/iphone](http://www.raima.com/iphone)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is installed on all iPhones. Theoretically, you can run other databases but since you cannot start other processes, you cannot run MySQL -- MySQL requires a separate process (the mysqld daemon).