# List of local/embedded databases for iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ipad, sqlite

Can someone post/suggest a list of local/embedded databases for iOS devices? (analogue of SQLite)
My question partially covered by [Can the iPhone only use an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316755/can-the-iphone-only-use-an-sqlite-database) though I suppose that there can be other DB which can work offline containing all data on mobile device.

EDIT: I've decided to gather all advices which I've received so far (10/09/2012 Thanks to Andy Dent and Raspu):

1. SQLite (obviously)
2. Raima RDM Embedded database (I haven't tried it)
3. CouchDB (it seems that they've dropped support, but I may be wrong) - https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iOS-Couchbase
4. Google's levelDB embedded key-value store. Objective-C wrappers: NuLevelDB, LevelDB-ObjC.
5. TokyoCabinet which is LGPL. Two wrappers: TSDocDB, BNRPersistence.

What else? It doesn't necessarily has to be SQL compatible DB (CouchDB for example), but it has to have a possibility to work locally on iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

Google's [levelDB embedded key-value store](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) reportedly works on iOS. There are at least two Objective-C wrappers for it - [NuLevelDB](http://blog.nulayer.com/post/12790995102/introducing-nuleveldb-for-ios) and [LevelDB-ObjC](https://github.com/hoisie/LevelDB-ObjC).

Comment: Thanks for this info, though my particular interest is a database, at least something that supports indexing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an embedded database for the iPhone, SQLite is the only database that will work.  However, if  you are talking about a database that will work with iPhone application development, there are many resources out there to choose from.

I noticed that you don't have much information on Raima.  I work for Raima so if you are still looking for our iOS database information, here is some more information about our products:

- Here's a video on Raima's product [RDM and its General Architecture](http://www.raima.com/rdm11-0-database-manager-video/)
- Here's a [Free evaluation download](http://www.raima.com/download-table/) of RDM Mobile

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are useful. Unfortunately I couldn't post more than 2 links in question that is why I didn't post links to Raima DB.

Comment: No problem! Did you have any other questions that you needed answered? Or anything that is confusing about our products?

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look to TokyoCabinet. Is LGPL, and some say that that license is not compatible with the AppStore, but I have used it before in a couple of apps. I have found this two wrappers:

- [TSDocDB](https://github.com/isaact/TSDocDB)
- [BNRPersistence](https://github.com/hillegass/BNRPersistence)

Anyway, I think LevelDB is better (even if it dosen't have indexing).

Comment: Thanks. This is a really interesting thing. Indeed there are problems with licensing for App Store though I can always play with it without releasing app.

Comment: And actually, Apple dosen't check licencies so thoroughly, I have uploaded an App using this DBs.